# PGF Plots stacked bar weird behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have a problem with the following pgfPlot, after changing some of the values, it's left padding is gone (see image) - does anyone have an idea why? I have tried changing xtick, changed some values, anything i can come up with. The last picture is how a correct plot should look like (it has half the number of bars though).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title=ITU (248362 interactions),
    title style={font=\bfseries},
    xbar stacked,
    bar width=8pt,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    symbolic y coords={1MM, 2MM, 3MM, 4MM, 1MM{(2)}, 2MM{(2)}, 3MM{(2)}, 4MM{(2)}},
    ytick=data,
    y=8mm,
    y tick label style={anchor=east},
    width=0.5\textwidth
    ]
    %Correct
    \addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates
    {(0.33,1MM)
        (0.29,2MM)
        (0.26,3MM)
        (0.14,4MM)
        (0.34,1MM{(2)})
        (0.33,2MM{(2)})
        (0.35,3MM{(2)})
        (0.36,4MM{(2)})};

    %Wrong
    \addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates
    {(0.64,1MM)
        (0.61,2MM)
        (0.49,3MM)
        (0.26,4MM)
        (0.66,1MM{(2)})
        (0.67,2MM{(2)})
        (0.65,3MM{(2)})
        (0.64,4MM{(2)})};

    %Not found
    \addplot+[xbar] plot coordinates
    {(0.03,1MM)
        (0.10,2MM)
        (0.25,3MM)
        (0.60,4MM)
        (0,1MM{(2)})
        (0,2MM{(2)})
        (0,3MM{(2)})
        (0,4MM{(2)})};
    \legend{Correct, Wrong, Not found}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Screeshot of wrong pgfplot]

[image: Screenshot of correct pgfplot]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding `xmin=0` to the options.